Downscaling liquidity tax according to ETH reserves for fair distribution without presale
So I wanted to try and solve the problems that arise when releasing a token with very low liquidity. Presaling should absolutely be avoided since holders always dump at the start.
Assume 50 to 100% of the entire token supply is deposited into the liquidity pool.
Auto-liquidity fees on transfer do eventually solve the problem, but you're left with very early buyers having a 100x+ impact over later buyers.
I wanted to solve this by implementing a downscaling liquidity tax at low ETH reserves, so as an example if token starts at $200 MC with the goal of $20,000 MC, then early buyers are taxed at 99% downscaling to 0%, and it should work in theory however I am not sure if the distribution would be fair.
A token's liquidity is always related to its 'true' market cap (if not theoretical), but it's not exact.
Ideally, buyers at $200 MC would have a 2x advantage over buyers at $2000 MC, and buyers at $2000 MC would have a 2x advantage over buyers at $20,000 MC, and so on until the liquidity pool reaches the target goal such as $20,000 and then the free market takes over.
However my current scaling distribution implementation is linear and it may not be foolproof.
This contract checks the current token reserves and taxes the receiver proportional to the current token ETH reserve held vs target ETH reserves. Then before every transfer it will swap and liquify those taxed tokens back into the Uniswap / PancakeSwap pair at the new elevated market price.
contract ScalingAutoLiquidity {
    struct TransferParams {
        bool Buy; bool Sell; bool Exit; bool Exempt;
    }

    bool microLiquidity = true;
    bool tradingActive = true;

    uint256 initialETHReserves = 1e18;
    uint256 targetETHReserves = 1e18 * 100;
    uint256 swapping = 1;
    uint256 swapTokensAtAmount = 1e15;

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint amount, bool forceExempt) internal returns (TransferParams memory Transaction) {

        // some logic like checking balances

        (Transaction.Buy, Transaction.Sell) = ((from == uniswapV2Pair), (to == uniswapV2Pair));

        Transaction.Exempt = (forceExempt || _isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to]);

        if (
            tradingActive && !Transaction.Exempt && swapping == 1
        ) {

            if (                             
                !Transaction.Buy &&                                     // from != uniswapV2Pair
                Transaction.Sell &&                                     // to = uniswapV2Pair
                (balanceOf(address(this)) > 0)                          // canSwap
            ) { 
                _swapAndLiquifyTokens(balanceOf(address(this)), address(0));   // lockTheSwap (during _swapAndLiquify, swapping is 2)
            }
        } 
    }

    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount, bool forceExempt) internal override {

        TransferParams memory Transaction = _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount, forceExempt);

        if (Transaction.Exit) { return; }

        if (Transaction.Exempt) {
            // sender, receiver, amount deducted from sender, amount sent to receiver
            _transferSupportingFee(from, to, amount, amount);
            return; 
        }
            
        uint256 microLiquidityTax;
        uint256 remainder;

        if (tradingActive && microLiquidity && Transaction.Buy) {

            (uint256 reserves0, uint256 reserves1, ) = IUniPair(PAIR).getReserves(); // cast to uint

            // Check Uniswap library sortTokens (token0 < token1)
            // uint256 currentTokenReserves = (address(this) < WETH) ? reserves0 : reserves1; 
            uint256 currentETHReserves = (address(this) < WETH) ? reserves0 : reserves1;

            // Example: ETH reserve is 1 ETH, target reserve is 20 ETH, 1/20 is 5%, micro liquidity tax is 95%
            microLiquidityTax = amount - ((amount * currentETHReserves) / targetETHReserves);

            // the amount remaining after liquidity tax is subtracted
            remainder = amount - microliquidityTax;

        } else {
            remainder = (amount * 5) / 100; // total taxes including liquidity
        }

        uint liquidity;
        
        if (microLiquidity) {
            liquidity = microLiquidityTax;
        } else {
            liquidity = (remainder / 100); // 1%
        }

        uint marketing = (remainder / 100); // 1%
        uint tFeeTotal = marketing + liquidity;
        
        _transferSupportingFee(from, to, amount, amount - tFeeTotal); // axiomatic

        _sendFeeTo(address(this), liquidity); // axiomatic
    }
}

